# Last step derivation of hamiltonian of particle in electromagnetic field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, hamiltonian

My textbook quantum mechanics does an analogues derivation of the hamiltonian as given [here](http://lampx.tugraz.at/%7Ehadley/ss1/IQHE/cpimf.php), but I'm struggling to understand the last step: The final obtained hamiltonian is (in my textbook's case)

$$H = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{\vec{x}} + eV$$

with V the electromagnetic potential, my professor (and the link) then claims that this is the same as:

$$H = \frac{1}{2m}(\vec{p} - \frac{e}{c}\vec{A})^2 + eV$$

but when I expand the bottom equation I get:

$$\frac{1}{2}m\dot{\vec{x}} + eV -\frac{e}{2mc}(\vec{A}\cdot\vec{p} + \vec{p}\cdot\vec{A}) + \frac{1}{2m}\left(\frac{e}{c}\right)^2A^2$$

How do the two terms on the right side cancel out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Expand bottom equation? Which one? It seems that you havent written $dx/dt$ in terms of conjugate momenta $p$.

Comment: Remember that $\vec p \neq m \dot {\vec x}$, but rather $\vec p = m \dot {\vec x}+\frac{e}{c}\vec A$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mistake you're making is in assuming that $$p_x = m \dot{x}.$$ **This is not true.** $m \dot{x}$ is known as the *kinetic momentum*, while $p_x$ is known as the conjugate momentum (to the coordinate $x$). In most (all?) problems in Classical Mechanics these two concepts are equal, but they aren't the same in general.

The conjugate momentum is obtained from the Lagrangian, using the relation $$p_x = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}}.$$

In most "usual" problems in Classical Mechanics, the only dependence the Lagrangian has on velocity is in the kinetic energy term, and thus $$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{x}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{x}}\left(\frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2\right) = m \dot{x},$$

but in electromagnetism, the Lagrangian is given by: $$\mathcal{L}_\text{em} = \frac{1}{2} m \dot{x}^2 - qV + q \dot{x}A_x,$$ and so $$p_x = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}_\text{em}}{\partial \dot{x}} = m \dot{x} + q A_x.$$

As a result, $m \dot{x} \neq  p_x$, but rather $$m \dot{x} = p_x - qA_x.$$ Using this in formula for the Hamiltonian: $$\mathcal{H} = \frac{1}{2}m \dot{x}^2 + qV = \frac{(p_x - qA_x)^2}{2 m} + q V.$$